# Auto update DATETIME column on insert with SQL?

Tags: mysql

I am currently just inserting `NOW()` into the date field on my database which works just fine but it got me wondering, is there a way to automatically update a `DATETIME` row upon inserting data?

I found online in some places that I should set the extras to `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` but when doing this I get the following error:

```
An error occurred when trying to change the field 'uploaded' via

ALTER TABLE `uploads` CHANGE `uploaded` `uploaded` DATETIME
 NOT NULL
 ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 COMMENT 'Upload Datetime'
```

MySQL said:

> Invalid ON UPDATE clause for 'uploaded' column

Comment: Which database are you using, please? You have four listed in your tags.

Comment: I'm currently using MySQL.

Comment: For SQL-SERVER, you can create a DATETIME column with a DEFAULT constraint set to GETDATE()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems the issue was that the column needed to be a `TIMESTAMP` not `DATETIME` upon changing it, I was able to successfully add the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` argument.

Answer (score 13):

This is what I do and it has always worked

```
create table if not exists my_table (
    index1 char(32) not null primary key,
    title varchar(50),
    my_timestamp timestamp not null default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp
)
```

This will have the timestamp on inserts and on updates, it also is valid sql, maybe you are missing the *default* statement in your query?

Comment: by the way, the reason why I put an example statement of *create* table and not alter table, is because the title of the question is more general than just alter tables, and people might come from google searching for a general answer.

Comment: Can we update the datetime based on the change in particular column? for example: if we want to update the 'my_timestamp' whenever someone changes the 'title' column? Is trigger required?

Comment: You could either do this outside of sql (e.g. with php), or you could also achieve this by putting the title in a separate table with its own timestamp.
Another method, which I don't like, is to add a trigger to the table, you can configure the trigger on every update to check if the `title` column changed, and if so update X timestamp column as well. I don't like this because it makes working with that table that much harder.

Answer (score 6):

Seems your query is wrong, try this out works for me:

```
ALTER TABLE `uploads` CHANGE `uploaded` `uploaded` 
DATETIME NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Tested it.

Comment: Whoever down voted should first run the query, it is working.

Comment: While this technically works, it should be using `modify`. `Change` is for changing the name of the column.

Comment: Nice, this works for me I couldn't do it manually. This query won't CHANGE the field name, just set the time stamp on updates.

Comment: But, thinking a little this date can be updated via '$sql' calculating the value with php

Answer (score 2):

Set the default value for the column upon table creation or alter it later.

In MySQL versions 5.6.5 and later:

```
default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

In SQL Server:

```
default getdate()
```

In PostgreSQL:

```
default now()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this documentation can help you a bit at understanding how to auto update the datetime in a sql database

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Hope this helped you :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! That is, indeed, a helpful link. But we like to avoid "link only answers" because links fall out of date, and to not be just an "RTFM" site. Could you expand your answer with some information about timestamps?

Comment: Ok, I will try to add more information to my answers and avoid the link answers. Thank you for your comment @Schwern

Answer (score 0):

For most SQL dialects, you can use a `DATETIME` column with a default of `current_timestamp`. That handles creation.

```
create table whatever (
    ...
    updated datetime default current_timestamp
);
```

Then add an `after update` trigger.

```
create trigger foo_updated
after update
on foo
for each row
begin
    update foo set updated = current_timestamp where id = new.id;
end;
```

---

MySQL has some special syntax to do this. You can make the trigger in your `create table` statement with an with an `on update`.

```
create table whatever (
    ...
    updated datetime default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp
);
```

---

And then there's [MySQL's `timestamp` date type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html). `Timestamp` will set itself to the current date and time anytime a row is updated... sorta.

The rules are very complicated which is why it's better to use `datetime` and `on update`.